# how to upload image or any file using hapijs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, hapi

How to save any type of file or image using Hapi.js

```
{
    method: "POST",
    path: apiUrl + "/company",
    config: {
        description: "Create Company api",
        auth: false,
        payload: {
            maxBytes: 20715200,
            output: "stream",
            parse: true,
            allow: "multipart/form-data",
        },
        
    },
    handler:  (request, h) => {
        const attributes = request.payload;
        //attributes.companyName    <<== Comapny name (Text)
        //attributes.logo           <<== company logo (Image)
        try {
            //how to save company logo in specific path
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
},
```

I am confusing for using which type of package or any? to save file

Answer (score 2):

Using @hapi/hapi: 18.x.x + version would help you with the below code.

```
server.route({
   method: "POST",
   path: apiUrl + "/company",
   handler:  (request, h) => {
      const attributes = request.payload;
      //attributes.companyName    <<== Comapny name (Text)
      //attributes.logo           <<== company logo (Image)
      try {
          //how to save company logo in specific path
      } catch (error) {
        
      }
   },
   options:{
      auth: false, // false by default
      payload: {
         parse: true,
         multipart: {
                output: 'stream'
         },
         maxBytes: 1000 * 1000 * 5, // 5 Mb
      }
   }
});
```

Happy coding!